# How to pull information from ngrx to component file

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have added the ngrx library to my project so that I may create a more reactive model for my data. I have set up my actions, reduces, effects files. I believe that these files work as they are intended to because I am able to see the populated model when logging the results in the effects file. However, I am unable to get these results to show up within a component. I have tried looking online for solutions but have had no luck. If anyone can spot a mistake in my code, please let me know how I can fix this issue. I will add the necessary code from the effects and component file as I believe the issue is present here. If somebody requests content from the other files, I will add this as well.

Effect:

```
@Effect()
getOperatorFacts: Observable<any> = this.actions
.pipe(
  ofType(GetOperatorFacts),
  map((action) => action),
  switchMap(action => this.operatorSanityService.getOperatorsThatHaveOperatorFacts(action.payload)
    .pipe(
      map(  (results: OperatorFacts) => {
        GetOperatorFactsSuccess({payload: results});
        console.log('From effects file', results);
      }),
      catchError((err) => of( GetOperatorFactsFailure({payload: err})))
    )
  )
);
```

Attempting to get the content from the component:

```
this.store.dispatch(GetOperatorFacts({payload: true}));
const x = this.store.pipe(select(getOperatorFactsState));
x.subscribe(res => {
  console.log('ajde ajde', res);
});
```

The following code spits out the following two errors:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Effect "OperatorFactsEffects.getOperatorFacts" dispatched an invalid action: undefined

ERROR TypeError: Actions must be objects
```

SOLUTION:

Adding the return statements before the success and failure functions as suggested by Marek W solved the errors in the code. Another problem I had was that in the selector I was returning state.OperatorFacts. Making a change so that it would only return the state was the correct call to make the information appear in the component file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the new action.

```
// code
map((results: OperatorFacts) => {
  console.log('From effects file', results);
  return new GetOperatorFactsSuccess({payload: results});
}),
// code
```

Same applies for your `catchError` block.

Comment: This solves the errors but undefined is returned in the component file.

Comment: And the `console.log()` inside your Effect prints out valid data?